# linked stack implementation

Tags: java

My problem here is with `pop` and size stack. I know that `pop` removes the top value and replaces it with the next value. How do I do that?

Also, what's the right way to get the size?

The code:

```
    public int pop()
    { 

          if (isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Pop attempted on an empty stack");
        else
        {
            return  m_top.value  ;  
        }

    }

    // return the size of the stack
    public int size()
    {       

          if (m_top == null)
        return 0;
        else
        return m_top.value; 
    }
```

Comment: *what's the right way to get the size* - store it as a field and increment it whenever you add a value, decrement when you remove a value

Comment: just think about the equivalents of the methods for linkedlists. This is pretty much the same as a linkedlist except for the public interface.

Comment: Let's start with the pop logic. You are returning the top value, which is correct, but you need a way to also make sure that the m_top variable now references the next variable in the stack. Can you think about where you have that reference so you could reassign it to m_top?

Comment: @cricket_007 that's **one** way - though the most efficient one -, but not the only one.

Comment: I suggest you read how the JDK does it in the built in LinkedList implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fine way to be able to retrieve the size of your stack at any moment is to maintain it internally.

As suggested by @Peter Lawrey in the comments, looking to real implementing in the JDK can be a great source of inspiration, even if it can be scary at the beginning.
For example, you will see that the size method in `LinkedList` is implemented this way, an internal `size` property is maintained for each linked list instance.

For the `pop` method, you need to have a precise idea of how you will implements your stack. For pop you at least need to be able to retrieve the previous item from the item at the top of your stack.
I see that you use a `Node` object internally, did you created this class? 
Is this a part of a homework? If you look closely to the linkedlist implementation again you will see that it also use a Node object (certainly not a coincidence...) that stores a reference to its next and previous object.

Comment: How doesn't it?  OP asks about the right way to get the size, and the first sentence in this answer addresses exactly that.  It also provides some more information on its implementation as well as suggestions on where to get started.

Comment: @JoshuaMacvey It does after the recent edit. Before it was just a plain copy-past of the comments on the question

Comment: I added the paragraph about the `pop` method after paul's comment. So its comment was sort of legitimate.

Comment: I agree that the answer was not complete, but not on the copy paste part. No big deal, since now cricket_007 made a more complete answer with implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that pop removes the top value and replaces it with the next value. How do I do that?

You need to reassign the `m_top` variable to it's `link`.

```
public int pop() {

    if (isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("Pop attempted on an empty stack");
    else {
        int top_value = m_top.value;
        // Move the top off the "stack" by moving the pointer
        m_top = m_top.link;
        return top_value;
    }
}
```

> way to get the size?

You count how many `Node`s are in the list instead of returning the `value` of the top `Node`. As mentioned in the comments, though, this is not the "most efficient way".

```
public int size() {
    int size = 0;

    if (isEmpty())
        return size;
    else {
        Node tmp = m_top;

        do {
            size++;
            tmp = tmp.link;
        } while (tmp != null);
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: `pop` usually throws an `EmptyStackException`, if the stack is empty. Atleast the stacks in the API behave that way.

Comment: @Paul - Just going off the OP's code. That is a comment for them, not me